# Can't POST value from view to controller in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, http-post

I need to post a value from a dropdownlist in form to my `HomeController`.

Here is the view:

```
@{
    
List<SelectListItem> listItems= new List<SelectListItem>();
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
      Text = "Title",
      Value = "@SortsMethods.Title",
    });
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "DeadLineDate",
        Value = "@SortsMethods.DeadLineDate",
    });
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "IsComplete",
        Value = "@SortsMethods.IsComplete"
    });
}

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
    
    <select asp-for="SortsMethods" asp-items="listItems">
    </select>
    
    <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

Here is the `HomeController`:

```
public readonly ITasksCommands _tasksCommands;
private readonly TasksDbContext _tasksDbContext;

public HomeController(ITasksCommands tasksCommands, TasksDbContext tasksDbContext)
{
    _tasksCommands = tasksCommands;
    _tasksDbContext = tasksDbContext;
}    

[Route("/")]
public async Task<ViewResult> Index()
{
    return View(new SortTypeModel()
    {
        Tasks = await _tasksCommands.GetTasks().ToListAsync(),
        SortsMethods = SortsMethods.Title
    });
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<SortTypeModel> Index(SortsMethods sortsMethods)
{
    var obj = _tasksCommands.GetTasks();
    switch (sortsMethods)
    {
        case SortsMethods.Title:
            obj = obj.OrderByDescending(x => x.Title);
            break;
        case SortsMethods.DeadLineDate:
            obj = obj.OrderByDescending(x => x.DeadlineDate);
            break;
        case SortsMethods.IsComplete:
            obj = obj.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsCompleted);
            break;
    }
    return new SortTypeModel()
    {
        Tasks = await obj.ToListAsync(),
        SortsMethods = SortsMethods.Title
    };
}
```

And these are the model classes:

```
namespace TasksApplication.Domain;

public class Tasks 
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeadlineDate { get; set; }
}

namespace WebApplication1.Models;

public class SortTypeModel 
{
    public SortsMethods SortsMethods { get; set; }

    public List<Tasks> Tasks { get; set; }

}

namespace TasksApplication.Application.Enum;

public enum SortsMethods
{
    Title, 
    DeadLineDate,
    IsComplete
}
```

My problem is that the controller doesn't receive `sortsMethods`, so it executes a default Index.

I've tried different dropdownlist forms, from manual `<select><option>...` where I write what is what, to this what I currently have.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try replacing `[HttpGet]` on your method, `Index(SortsMethods sortsMethods)`, with `[HttpPost]`. If you want that method to receive the form post then you need to allow it by using `[HttpPost]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routing configuration, `[Route("/")]` will cause the method you submit to only enter the get method. Therefore, you need to ensure that the GET and POST methods are clearly distinguished. You can use `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` to mark them or specify different routing templates for them.
In addition, you can get the value of the drop-down list through `asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<SortsMethods>()"`. Here is an example for your reference:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"> 
    <select asp-for="SortsMethods" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<SortsMethods>()">
        <option value="">-- Select sort by --</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpGet("/")]
public async Task<ViewResult> Index()
{
    //code in method
}


[HttpPost]
public async Task<SortTypeModel> Index(SortsMethods sortsMethods)
{
   // code in method
}
```

when I submit data:

[image]

Controllers can accept requests as well as data:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked! By some reason this works only when I get values with GetEnumSelectList

Answer (score 2):

If you want to POST the value of SortsMethods to the controller, then your best bet would be to write an endpoint that accepts a POST operation:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Index(SortTypeModel viewModel)
{
   viewModel.SortsMethods....
```

I would also heavily advise that you initialize the select list in your GET endpoint and pass that data to the view using your view model.

Hopefully this is enough to get you going.